# Can a method return a T(generic) as type (like int, bool, DateTime etc.)?

Tags: c#, generics

I am wondering if there is a way that a method that returns a generic can return an int or bool or any other data type. For example:

```
private static T GetDefaultValue<T>(SettingType s)
{
  switch(s)
  {
    case s.IntValue:
      return 0;
    case s.BoolValue:
      return false;
    case s.DateTimeValue:
      return DateTime.MinValue;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And be used further like:

```
...
int x = GetDefaultValue<int>(s.IntValue)
...
```

I know that this can be achieved by using object as return type or using overloading, but was wandering if it can also work with generics.

Comment: In this case it would be just `return default(T)`. But no, generics are meant for solving *generic* problems, i.e. those problems which can apply transparently to different types.

Comment: Beyond default, the general pattern is `(T) (object) myValue`. This will necessarily involve a runtime conversion, so it's sort of missing the point of the compile-time safety of generics.

Comment: You could probably even go without the `SettingType`: `Type type = typeof(T); if (type == typeof(int)){ /* do int stuff */ } else if (type == typeof(bool) { /* do bool stuff */  }) [etc.]` -- sadly `Type` doesn't play with `switch`.

Comment: @Corak: that's why `Type.GetTypeCode` exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can but you have to fight the compiler a little bit, you need to cast through object for this to work

```
private static T GetDefaultValue<T>(SettingType s)
{
  switch(s)
  {
    case s.IntValue:
      return (T)(object)0;
    case s.BoolValue:
      return (T)(object)false;
    case s.DateTimeValue:
      return (T)(object)DateTime.MinValue;
  }
  throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported type")
}
```

Comment: It would be better if the default case would throw a meaningful exception. This way you will get an `InvalidCastException` in runtime instead.

Comment: @Groo you are right, I just copied the original code and made it compilable. I edited the answer to reflect your feedback